# Pushing Nuget packages to Orchard Gallery Server

Tags: nuget, orchardcms-1.6

The guys at Orchard use a web service as a feed for Orchard modules which is freely available here:

https://orchardgallery.codeplex.com/

I've gotten this up and running, but for the life of me can't seem to push any Nuget packages into it. According to this discussion [here](https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/304350) it's necessary to use an older version of Nuget.exe, version 1.2 to do the push. Well I've tried that (using both a nupkg I downloaded from the Orchard site, and also one I created myself) with:

```
 nuget-1.2 push Orchard.Module.Contrib.Profile-1.1.nupkg -s http://localhost:85/FeedService.svc/
```

But while it doesn't give any error, nothing appears in the database, and nothing appears in the feed when I browse to:

```
 http://localhost:85/FeedService.svc/Packages()
```

I get:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <feed xml:base="http://localhost:85/FeedService.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <title type="text">Packages</title>
 <id>http://localhost:85/FeedService.svc/Packages</id>
 <updated>2013-06-24T01:44:09Z</updated>
 <author>
  <name />
 </author>
 <link rel="self" title="Packages" href="Packages" />
 </feed>
```

Has anyone successfully managed to publish a package to Orchard's Gallery Server?

Comment: The answer at this stage appears to be "don't use this"! The guys at Orchard are planning on revisiting this at some time, but as of right now it should be avoided lest you spend a couple of futile days trying to get it work like we did!

Answer (score 1):

You want to push to the root, not to the .svc as the .svc is expecting OData not packages.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a free MyGet.org feed and any version of the NuGet client tools. Each MyGet feed also has a v1 endpoint which is compatible with Orchard.

You could configure the MyGet feed as an extra Orchard gallery, or you could configure the Orchard Gallery as an upstream package source of your MyGet feed and promote the package from MyGet to the Orchard Gallery.

More info at https://docs.myget.org/docs/reference/package-sources